# AWK in single line pass multiple commands

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to combine the following multiple awk commands into a single awk program:

```
awk -F 'FS' '{ $1 = ($1 == "}" ? "" : $1) } 1' sorce > destfil
awk -F 'FS' '{ $3 = ($3 == "]" ? "" : $3) } 1' sorce > destfil
awk -F 'FS' '{ $5 = ($5 == "}" ? "}," : $5) } 1' sorce > destfil
```

I have tried to accomplish this using `&&` but the result is not what I expected.

```
awk -F 'FS' '{ $1 = ($1 == "}" ? "" : $1) &&  $3 = ($3 == "]" ? "" : $3) && $5 = ($5 == "}" ? "}," : $5) } 1' sorce > destfil
```

The output seems to have various ZERO's in it.

**Question:**

- How can I merge these lines?
- What is the origin of the ZEROS?

Thank you!

---

@RavinderSingh13, as I tried your code, sample input file and output file as per below

```
[user@restt]$ tail source
    {
    }
  ]
}
{
  " e t
    {
    }
  ]
}
[user@test]$ awk -F 'FS' '{$1=($1=="}"?"":$1); $3=($3=="]" ? "" : $3) ; $5=($5=="}" ? "}," :$5);} 1' source > target
[user@test]$ tail target
    {
    }
  ]
}
{
  " e t
    {
    }
  ]
}
```

I think the issue is related to field separator -F 'FS' or I was not sure.

---

@kvantour, Below I have given my sample input file & command what I am running & what output I am getting & what I require.

Source file content :

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    }
  ]
}
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    }
  ]
}
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    }
  ]
}
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    }
  ]
}
```

A command I am running

```
$ awk '($1=="}"){$1="First Column"}
       ($3=="]"){$3="third Column"}
       ($5=="}"){$5="Fifth Column"}
       {$1=$1}1' sample.json > out
```

Output I am getting :

```
[root@centos-src ~]# cat out

{
"metadata": [
{
sample content line 1
sample content line n


First Column
]
First Column
{
"metadata": [
{
sample content line 1
sample content line n


First Column
]
First Column
{
"metadata": [
{
sample content line 1
sample content line n


First Column
]
First Column
{
"metadata": [
{
sample content line 1
sample content line n


First Column
]
First Column
```

but I am expecting output is:

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    Fifth Column
  third Column
First Column
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    Fifth Column
  third Column
First Column
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    Fifth Column
  third Column
First Column
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      sample content line 1
      sample content line n


    Fifth Column
  third Column
First Column
```

Comment: Are you sure your field separator value is `FS` only in your Input_file?

Comment: Yes it's FS only

Comment: Please, post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: @kesava, always try to add samples of input and output in your posts, try my solution once?

Comment: Thanks for quick replay! I have tried your solution. But only first argument it's affecting remaining is not changing. I will try to add hear output files

Comment: Your posted files of `source` and `target` look identical to me. By `source` do you mean `input` and by `target` do you mean `desired output` (the 2 things we **need** to see)? What is the difference between them? What is `-F 'FS'` supposed to do? What does `I am getting the output file with all 00` mean? This is your 4th question and so far you haven't accepted an answer to any of them and your rep is still `1` - read [ask] and the comments you received to your previous questions so you can learn how to ask better questions and so stand a chance of getting an answer you want.

Comment: Hi ED Morton, first I try with my code that time error was 00 as I mentioned then I tried the code of @RavinderSingh13, at that time i am getting same output that i posted later (i have edited the question) for giving sample input-output code.

Comment: Do you have literal `'FS'` in your input file as the field separator?  Please post the input with field separators.

Comment: @kesava, answer which you accepted is similar to other answers, please do let us know what didn't work on all other answers in comments so that all will be knowing it too.

Comment: This question makes zero sense. The only way you can get output that's `all 00` is if the input is `all 00` but there's no sign of `00`s in the `source` (sample input), there's also no sign of a string `FS` in the `source` you posted, the `source` bears no resemblance to anything your script might be trying to do, nor what the accepted answer does, the accepted answer does exactly what the script in your question that you claim doesn't work does, and there's no expected output provided. I've no idea what this was all about!

Comment: Hi All, It's all the answers are the same but there is no option to select all the answers. FS is default space only and if u see my sample input file there is no field separator.

Comment: @EdMorton The zero's make sense. Look at the OP's one-liner and consider the precedence between `expr1 && expr2` and `lvalue = expr`. I have updated my answer trying to explain this.

Comment: @kesava I have updated the answer to explain your zeros. I would however rewrite the sentence _"I am getting the output file with all 00"_ with _"Why does this one-liner sets `$1` and `$3` to ZERO"_.

Comment: @kesava I have updated your question to make a couple of things more clear. However, we would like to have an example of your input file and output which produces those ZERO values. Also, from the answer you gave to RavinderSingh13, it looks to me that you might misinterpret the meaning of `FS`. The input file you show us by means of `tail source` does not have any reference of the string `"FS"`. Could it be that there is a misinterpretation here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nice awk structure, one would write:

```
awk -F 'FS' '($1=="}"){$1=""}
             ($3=="]"){$3=""}
             ($5=="}"){$5="},"}
             {$1=$1}1' <file>
```

The reason I add `$1=$1` to the list, is to reprocess `$0` for the correct `OFS` in case none of the above conditions was satisfied. If you don't do this, you will have lines printed with `FS` as field separator and others with `OFS`.

**So why are you getting a bunch of zeros?**

Let's look at your one-liner:

```
$1 = ($1 == "}" ? "" : $1) &&  $3 = ($3 == "]" ? "" : $3) && $5 = ($5 == "}" ? "}," : $5)
```

And simplify it by assuming that the ternary operators between brackets return a variable. So we can rewrite it as:

```
$1 = var1 && $3 = var3 && $5 = var5
```

Taking into account that:

- `expr1 && expr2` has a higher precedence than `value = expr`.
- `lvalue = expr` returns the value of expr

We can see that awk interprets this as

```
$1 = var1 && ($3 = (var3 && ($5 = var5) ) )
```

So the result will be:

```
$5 = var5
$3 = var3 && $5  equalling var3 && var5
$1 = var1 && $3  equalling var1 && var5
```

This is visible in the following example:

```
$ echo "a b c d e f" | awk '{ $1="p" && $3 = "q" && $5 = "r"}1'
1 b 1 d rf
```

Finally, in `awk` an empty string and a numeric zero has the logical value **false** and anything else **true**. So since two of your original ternary operators *can* return empty strings, they will ensure that the logical AND will return false, which is equivalent to the number ZERO. Hence `$1` and `$3` will be both matched with ZERO if the original `$3` equals `]`

### Update (after receiving [mcve])

What you try to achieve is not that easy. First off, it seems you assume that the column number implies the character number in the line. This is sadly not the case. Awk, in default mode, assumes that field `$n` is the `n`th word in the line where a word is a sequence of characters not containing any blank. So in the following text,

```
    }
  ]
}
```

all characters are actually referenced by `$1`.

Under the assumption that your JSON file is perfectly indented, one could use the following:

```
awk '/^} *$/{$0="First Column"}
     /^  ] *$/{$0="  Thrid Column"}
     /^    } *$/{$0="    Fifth Column"}
     {print $0}' <file>
```

However, if your JSON file is not indented uniformly, things become rather messy. The easiest would be to parse the file first with `jq` as

```
jq . <json-file> | awk ...
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your explanation, with your reference code, I can able to change normal text files but hear my file is JSON program file so in front of the line spaces are there. If i run these examples output file becomes a text file (that means no spaces before the lines).

Comment: @kesava I am a bit puzzled now. Could you please edit your question and provide us with a snippet of the input file you try to convert, the output you obtain with your command and the output you try to achieve ([mcve]). Currently, many of us are trying to help you out, but it seems we are all missing this vital information as everybody is giving answers to his own interpretation of the question. So please, provide us _an input file example_, _the output you obtain_ and _the expected output how it should look_.

Comment: Sure I am providing input files and output files and pasting what I want. Hope that will help u to understand more.

Comment: @kesava I have updated the answer. I hope this explains things a bit.

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do (given your `source` input file)?

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ FS="[ ]"; map[1,"}"]=map[3,"]"]=map[5,"}"]="" }
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=((i,$i) in map ? map[i,$i] : $i); print }
' file
    {



{
  " e t
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown your sample Input_file so couldn't test it, could you please try following.

```
awk -F 'FS' '{$1=($1=="}"?"":$1);$3=($3=="]"?"":$3);$5=($5=="}"?"":$5);} 1' sorce > destfil
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, what is the reason for down vote? Please mention.

Comment: I have given up on these kinds of queries. Some more information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/)

Answer (score 0):

Usage `;` to separate statements:

```
awk ... '{ $1 = ($1 == "}" ? "" : $1); $3 = ($3 == "]" ? "" : $3); $5 = ($5 == "}" ? "}," : $5); } 1' ...
```